# Choosing users for A/B testing

Tags: c#, .net

I have a table with userid's (int increment) about 4M records.

I would like to show a new feature to only 25% of the users.

What would be the best way to choose those 25% users?

Comment: Add another table with the `studentid` and `featureid`

Comment: What do you have in mind? Any random 25% users or users meeting a certain criteria. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: ie.  For 50% I will ask if N%2=0 then show new feature

Comment: How about, when they login, they have a 25% chance of being in the B group.  Just set it on the session.  When they login next time, they get another bucket.

Comment: why not use the same logic for every fourth user.  Something like if (userID / 4) = INT(userID / 4) then [approve feature]?  Not truly random but should be random enough.

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to stack overflow! Don't worry, this happens to everyone. Please try to edit your question to provide more details and hopefully your question will be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

you could use some sort of [Fisher Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle algorithm to randomly choose the 'first' 25% of user ids.

ie, pick a random number between 1 and 4M. that's your first user, add it to a collection somewhere. repeat until you have 1M (25%) users in your collection.

Once you have all the users, mark them somehow in your table.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if (user.Id <= (maxId * 0.25))
{
    // Show a new feature
}
```

Comment: Might be an issue as it won't be random but will instead be the oldest 25% of the users ( in terms of when they were created).

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is that you could set a browser cookie which was 'myAwesomeFeature=A' or 'myAwesomeFeature=B'. If the cookie isn't set yet, set it to 'B' if a random number between 0-100 is 25 or less. 'A' otherwise. If the cookie is already set, just use it.

Has the added benefit of being easily testable since you can easily force yourself to be in whichever group you want. And it'll work for multiple features since you just need to change the cookie name. And the same user will get the same group as long as the cookie doesn't expire.